# UINavigationController mandatory or not when using push segue

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, segue

I have a **UINavigationController** to switch between my **UIViewContollers**, but I'm not using the **NavigationTopBar** which is hidden. I have just a custom **imageButton**  to switch back on the previous **ViewController**, so I did a push segue between the **imageButton** and the previous **ViewController**.

Everything works but I dont know if it's the good way to do this or instead it's better to use the **NavigationTopBar**.

My only problem is that when I want to switch back, when I click on the **imageButton** the view comes from the right to the left, and I want that the view comes from the left to the right, like when you use the **NavigationTopBar** back button.

How can I do that ?

1. I keep the **imageButton** to switch back without the **NavigationTopBar**.
2. I use the **NavigationTopBar** and I customize the back button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```